# Query a table using a variable set by a built in function MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to use a variable that is set by a function using mysql but I just cant figure it out.
It just keeps giving me errors.

My sql code looks like this right now. What I am trying to do is find the employee with the highest salary by storing the highest salary in a variable and then using that in the select query. Unless you cannot do this this way.

```
SET @max_value := MAX(salary)
#SET @max_value = MAX(employees.salaries.salary);
SELECT * from salaries Where salary > @max_value;
```

But this does not work

Comment: You need to put that max into a select statement. Although your objective seems questionable. And don't use > with max, no value is bigger than the biggest in the set

Comment: Illogical. Your pseudocode tries to select rows which have column values above the greatest value in this column...

Comment: Ah yes the > was a hold over as I was reusing the code a bit for other test. It should be = not >

Answer (score 3):

You have to set variable like this:

```
SET @max_value := (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM salaries);
```

OR

```
SELECT MAX(salary) INTO @max_value FROM salaries;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just look up the max in a subquery?

Though I strongly suspect you meant `>=`; there will be no salaries greater than the max (unless you mean to be getting the max salary to compare from some other table?)

```
SELECT * from salaries where salary >= (SELECT MAX(salary) from salaries)
```

Or use the RANK window function, which isn't as friendly for `SELECT *` (which you shouldn't do anyway):

```
SELECT id, other cols FROM (
    SELECT id, other cols, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) r
    FROM salaries
) ranked_salaries
WHERE r=1;
```